# How can I open an image from a RecyclerView in a separate activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The app I am working on currently includes a Gallery View that shows several images. These are shown in a `recycler view`. What I'd ultimately like to accomplish is to have the user tap on one of the images and have it open as an `image view` in a separate activity. I am hoping I can learn the way this can best be done. I couldn't find it in search, and please forgive me, I am still very new to coding.

Gallery Activity:

```js
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    private final Integer image_ids[] = {
           //all of my image ids from drawable//



    };

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent returnhome = new Intent(GalleryActivity.this, BleachActivity.class);
        startActivity(returnhome);
        finish();
        return;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("//name of app//");


        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 3);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        ArrayList<Cell> cells = prepareData();
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cells);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    private ArrayList<Cell> prepareData() {
        ArrayList<Cell> theImage = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < image_ids.length; i++){
            Cell cell = new Cell();
            cell.setImg(image_ids[i]);
            theImage.add(cell);

    }

    return theImage;

}}
```

Cell java file:

```js
public class Cell {

    private Integer img;

    public Integer getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(Integer img) {
        this.img = img;
    }
}
```

Image Adapter Java file:

```js
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Cell> galleryList;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<Cell> galleryList){
        this.galleryList = galleryList;
        this.context = context;

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, final int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);}

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i){
        viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        viewHolder.img.setImageResource(galleryList.get(i).getImg());
        viewHolder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return galleryList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private ImageView img;
        public ViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);

            img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first create a new activity that holds and image view say ImageViewActivity.
Then you have multiple choices, we will review two of them.

**Easy not great choice (not great architectural wise)**

Start the activity from your adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i){
    viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    viewHolder.img.setImageResource(galleryList.get(i).getImg());
    viewHolder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ImageViewActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

**Better way**

A better way is to use delegate pattern. Explanation: it is not the adapter's responsibility to know what to do when an item is clicked. Hence that knowledge should be somewhere else, for simplicity, it could in your activity.

**MyAdapter**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> { 

    public class Delegate {
        public void onClick(int imageResource);
    }

    private Delegate delegate;

    public MyAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<Cell> galleryList, Delegate delegate){
        this.galleryList = galleryList;
        this.context = context;
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i){
        viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        viewHolder.img.setImageResource(galleryList.get(i).getImg());
        viewHolder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                delegate.onClick(galleryList.get(i).getImg());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**GalleryActivity**

```
public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyAdapter.Delegate {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

        ...

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cells, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageViewActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

If you are really interested in what part of the code should be where you can take a look at architectural patterns like MVC, MVP, MVVM or Clean Architecture (the later is supposed to overtake the rest).
There are example projects provided by google with different architectures:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method in the adapter that uses the clicked item information and passes it on to the activity as an extra.

For example:

```
viewHolder.img.setImageResource(galleryList.get(i).getImg());
```

You can use this line to get the image and add it as an extra.

To get the specific item data, you can use something like this in the adapter's view holder:

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                    galleryList.get(pos).getImg());
                }
}
```

And then finish the job by adding.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
myIntent.putExtra("extraName", value);
startActivity(myIntent);
```